# work visa to Qatar

Tags: visas, work, qatar

I have Qatar  work visa mailed to me by my employer. It contains my old passport number which has ECR stamp.
I then got a new passport issued without ECR stamping, but with different passport number. I have both passports.
Can I travel to Qatar now?

Comment: Are both passports valid?

Comment: The emmigration stack exchange site might be a better place to ask

Comment: This [Ministry of Overseas Indian Affairs website](http://www.moia.gov.in/services.aspx?ID1=111&id=m6&idp=104&mainid=73) does not list Qatar as an ECNR (emigration check not required) country.